# Hot stream subscription with react custom hook

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, rxjs

I need to subscribe to a hot stream in a React custom hook. This means, that the Ajax request is not completing. It keeps receiving data chunks (well-formed JSON) from the server endless.

My source code looks like this:

```
export const useQData = (
  resourceId: string,
): {
  qDataResult: Result<QData>;
} => {
  const [qData, setQData] = useState<Result<QData>>({ status: "initial" });

  function handleQData(qData: Result<QData>) {
    setQData(qData);
  }

  // get qData initially
  useEffect(() => {
    debugger;
    const observable = ajax
      .getJSON<QData>(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/subscription/msnOutput/${resourceId}`)
      .pipe(startWith(<QData>{ tileStatus: "NOTILE" }));
    const c = connectable<QData>(observable);
    c.connect();
    const subscription = c.subscribe({
      next: (response) => handleQData({ status: "update", payload: response }),
      error: (error) => handleQData({ status: "error", responseErrorCode: 404, messageId: error.message }),
      complete: () => handleQData({ status: "offline" }), // stream completed
    });
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe();
  }, []);

  return {
    qDataResult: qData,
  };
};
```

For some reason the stream does not start. Even the initial values set by `startWith()`is not processed. Do I miss something to start the processing?

UPDATE:

I have achieved getting the processing to run by setting `includeDownloadProgress: true` for the Ajax request. Here is the source code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    observable = ajax<string>({
        url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/subscription/msnOutput/${resourceId}`,
        includeDownloadProgress: true,
        responseType: "text",
      }).pipe(
        // Extract response body from response object
        map((response) => response.response),
        filter((responseString) => responseString !== ""),
        // Extract response objects
        map((responseString) => responseString.split("\n")),
        filter((responseArray) => responseArray.length > 0),
        // Find last valid qdata object
        map((responseArray) => extractValidQDataString(responseArray)),
        filter((qDataString) => qDataString !== ""),
        map((qDataString) => JSON.parse(qDataString) as QData),
        startWith(<QData>{ tileStatus: "NOTILE" }),
      );
    const c = connectable(observable);
    const s = c.subscribe({
      next: (response) => setQData({ status: "update", payload: response }),
      error: (error) => handleError(error),
      complete: () => setQData({ status: "offline" }), // stream completed
    });
    c.connect();
    setSubscription(s);
    return () => s.unsubscribe();
  }, []);
```

Unfortunately, the result of download progress responses has several disadvantages:

- It contains a growing array of responses
- The response cannot be retrieved as JSON directly
  Does anyone has an idea how to address these shortcomings?

Comment: What happens if you put `c.connect()` **after** `const subscription = c.subscribe({...})` ? By using `c.connect()`, the `observable` will be subscribed and since `startWith` is a sync action, the value will be sent immediately. However, the problem is that by that time, there are no subscribers yet, because the subscription step comes after that.

Comment: Thanks @AndreiGătej, this helped to get the initial data item processed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It contains a growing array of responses

The core issue is that the `AjaxResponse` emitted by `ajax()` (the same object each time) has a `response` property that [grows with each chunk](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2016/05/24/fetch-and-xhr-limitations/#:%7E:text=It%E2%80%99s%20possible%20to%20set%20up%20a%20stream%20in%20XHR%2C%20but%20it%20would%20cause%20the%20responseText%20to%20continuously%20grow%2C%20and%20you%20would%20have%20to%20constantly%20retrieve%20the%20data%20manually%20from%20there.). I'm guess this long polling is to maintain support for older browsers?

If not, I would recommend **using the Fetch API instead** - the article I linked just now explains in detail.

```
const streamResponseBody = (url: string): Observable<string> =>
  from(fetch(url)).pipe(
    op.concatMap((resp) => {
      const reader = resp.body?.getReader();
      if (!reader) {
        return throwError(() => new Error('response had no body to read'));
      }
      const encoder = new TextDecoder();
      return defer(() => reader.read()).pipe(
        op.repeat(),
        op.takeWhile(({ done }) => !done),
        op.map(({ value }) => encoder.decode(value)),
        op.filter((value) => value !== '')
      );
    })
  );
```

Now we have a stream of chunks, but we want a stream of lines so we can easily convert them to `QData`. Reading your code, it looks like it's safe to assume that every newline-separated string of characters is potentially parse-able as `QData`. This operator buffers chunks and emits complete lines as they arrive.

```
const chunksToLines: MonoTypeOperatorFunction<string> = pipe(
  op.scan(
    (acc, chunk) => {
      const lines = acc.buffer.concat(chunk).split('\n');
      return {
        lines: lines.slice(0, lines.length - 1),
        buffer: lines[lines.length - 1],
      };
    },
    { buffer: '', lines: [] as readonly string[] }
  ),
  op.concatMap(({ lines }) => lines)
);
```

> The response cannot be retrieved as JSON directly

Yep, that's unavoidable. Nothing `rxjs` exports is going to integrate directly with your particular long-polling implementation. But your code can still get to a pretty clean place:

```
// This function is a combination of extractValidQDataString and
// JSON.parse(qDataString), except it doesn't have to handle arrays.
declare const stringToQData: (input: string) => QData | undefined;

useEffect(() => {
 const s = streamResponseBody(
   `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/subscription/msnOutput/${resourceId}`
 )
   .pipe(
     chunksToLines,
     op.map(stringToQData),
     op.filter((value): value is QData => !!value),
     op.startWith(<QData>{ tileStatus: 'NOTILE' })
   )
   .subscribe({
     next: (response) => setQData({ status: 'update', payload: response }),
     error: (error) => handleError(error),
     complete: () => setQData({ status: 'offline' }), // stream completed
   });
 setSubscription(s);
 return () => s.unsubscribe();
}, []);
```

One other thing worth pointing out: example as written does not take advantage of the "hot" observable. The functionality would be the same without using `connect` and just subscribing directly. This is because the connected observable is inaccessible outside the `useEffect` callback and thus can take on no additional subscribers.